# Find the timestamp of last buffer flush in Fluentd

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd, efk

I am new to Fluentd (and the hole EFK stack). I have Fluentd which sends the logs to Elasticsearch (both in Kubernetes) and I am trying to find a way to find the time when the last (successful) flush of the buffer happened.

I can think of two ways but both look like workarounds and lead to additional problems:

1. To use some proxy between the Fluentd and Elasticsearch
2. Somehow to make fluentd itself to log more logs and check for the proper log.

Is there some other more beautiful way?

Comment: Why not just monitor the time stamp of the most recent log in ES?

Comment: Because the Elasticsearch and the Fluentd are in different clusters, I forgot to mention that, sorry. And I want to find the last flush in kubernetes in which fluentd is running without contacting the other cluster.